# SWIFTUI: Trouble using FirebaseFirestoreSwift

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, viewmodel

i am struggling to implement use FirebaseFirestoreSwift to decode data fetched from Firestore into my model (RestaurantModel). The code seem right, but when building this in the Simulator it is not showing the results.

Could use an extra pair of eyes to see if i am missing anything.

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
```

Here is the Model:

```
public struct Model: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable, Equatable {
    @DocumentID public var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
    
    let item0: String
    let item1: String
    
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case item0
        case item1
        case timestamp
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [Model]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchDataListener() {
        db.collection("items")
            .limit(to: 10)
            .order(by: "uid")
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("DEBUG: No Documents fetched")
                    return
                }
                
                self.items = documents.compactMap { snapshot -> Model? in
                    
                    return try? snapshot.data(as: Model.self)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the View:

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(viewModel.items) { item in
            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                Text(item.item0)
                    .font(.headline)
                Text(item.item1)
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Items")
        .onAppear() {
            self.viewModel.fetchDataListener()
        }
    }}

struct ListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListView()}
}
```

This is how it looks in the Simulator. I expect the List to show the fetch results from FireStore:

[image]

Comment: More often than not this is due to decoding issues which you are ignoring, for a “quick” fix you can make the model variables optional and see if it shows anything

Comment: Also change the ObservedObject to StateObject

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I had to change all the model variables to optional to solve the issue as some items in the model was nil, it would not allow the decoder to finish. Adding DO TRY CATCH helped me finding the exact variables requiring to be made optional.